# CSS Grid Images don't scale vertically

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid, scale

I'm currently working on a project, in which I have to display images in a grid layout. The natural thing for me was to use CSS grid. I have a working solution, which looks good only for certain aspect ratios (portrait aspect ratios). As soon as the aspect ratio is more on the landscape side (especially 16:9), the overall grid doesn't fit the screen anymore. It seems that the images are the problem because they don't "scale" vertically.

Looks good for "portrait" aspect ratios:
[image: Solution looks good for certain aspect ratios]

Looks bad for "wide" aspect ratios:
[image]

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.client {
  display: grid;
  border: 3px solid black;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px;
}

.client-title {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.client-description {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.exercise-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="client">
    <div class="client-title">
      Title Text 1
    </div>

    <!-- Repeated 8 times -->
    <div class="exercise">
            <img class=" exercise-image " src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="client-description ">
           Description Text 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="client ">
        <div class="client-title ">
            Title Text 2
        </div>

        <!-- Repeated 8 times -->
        <div class="exercise">
      <img class="exercise-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="client-description">
      Description Text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you have an idea, what I miss here?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually do in the class "exercise-image". Do I need to use it somewhere else?

Comment: sorry, I miss it in your CSS. Try to add `display: block` in `.exercise-image`

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, `display: block` didn't lead to success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the height of the `.client` grid directly to full viewport height and remove `height: 100vh` of its grid container element `.container`.
   That works because now the heights of the grid rows of the '.client' grid get calculated directly relative to viewport's current height.
   And the containing element adapts to that childs height accordingly.
2. Set the `min-height` of the `.exercise` grid item, that contains each rows image, to 0 to override the default value (min-width/min-height: auto is the CSS Grid default setting) and thus, to make the image shrinkable below its own size.

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  // height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.client {
  display: grid;
  border: 3px solid black;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px;
  height: 100vh; // height: 100%;
}

.client-title {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.client-description {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.exercise {
  min-height: 0;
}

.exercise-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The missing `"` wasn't the problem. I made a mistake, when I created a reduced version of my code for the Stack Overflow question. In my original code, the `"` is not missing. I edited the question.

Comment: @Johannes Hasreiter Ok, i have reworked my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, your instructions did the trick. My key takeaway is that those height/width computations have problems with encapsulated grids. Too bad. Especially for (container) grids that have more than 1 row, I have to compute the height on my own to be able to specify it with `vh`.